# How to reduce XML reading cost in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am reading a xml value and storing in a table but its cost is 82%.

This is my query:

```
declare @StateNameList XML 
set @StateNameList='<StatusList>
                        <Status>
                            <StatusName>All</StatusName>
                            <StatusID>1</StatusID>
                        </Status>
                        <Status>
                            <StatusName>test</StatusName>
                            <StatusID>2</StatusID>
                        </Status>
                    </StatusList>'

SELECT 
    Table1.Column1.value('(./StatusName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS StatusName 
FROM 
    @StateNameList.nodes('/StatusList/Status') AS Table1(Column1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below code after from tag then see the execution plan

```
declare @StateNameList XML 
set @StateNameList='<StatusList>
                        <Status>
                            <StatusName>All</StatusName>
                            <StatusID>1</StatusID>
                        </Status>
                        <Status>
                            <StatusName>test</StatusName>
                            <StatusID>2</StatusID>
                        </Status>
                    </StatusList>'

SELECT 
    Table1.Column1.value('(./StatusName)[1]','varchar(50)') AS StatusName 
FROM 
    @StateNameList.nodes('/StatusList/Status') AS Table1(Column1) 
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ( @StateNameList = NULL ))
```

Comment: It's not huge performance  changes but u will able to reduce half of the cost (%) value. Like 82 % 46 % to